# How to secure laravel projecet on Synology NAS?

Tags: php, laravel, security, deployment, synology

I deployed laravel project on my synology. And it can be accessed already using IPADDRESS\ProjectName\public. All the function run well already.

But the problem is, my .env is exposed too in \IPADDRESS\ProjectName.env

I have tried :

- Add .httaccess :
  options -Indexes
  <Files .env>
  order allow,deny
  Deny from all
- change permission to 640 too

All that steps make .env cannot be accessed from outside/local, but my laravel project cannot run too.

So how can I run my laravel project on Synology without exposs my .env file?

Comment: i think that you need change path .env in core from laravel. But the better solution it´s set your app in debug mode, yes, i know that it´s strange... and in config/app.php set your conflictive variables in debug_blacklist

Comment: i tried it already. but when i access it using \\IPADDRESSS\.env, i can see all the content in that .env file.